# Numpy: reshape list of tuples

Tags: python, numpy, reshape, numpy-ndarray

I have the following list of tuples:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> import numpy as np
>>> grid = list(itertools.product((1,2,3),repeat=2))
>>> grid
[(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3)]
```

I'd like to reshape this list in a sensible way (e.g. using numpy if possible) to be 3x3 as follows:

```
[[(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3)],
 [(2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3)],
 [(3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3)]]
```

When I do `np.reshape(grid, (3, 3))` I get the following error: `ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 18 into shape (3,3)` (size 18??)

I've tried variations of `np.reshape(grid, (3, 3, 2))` but these don't return the 3x3 grid given above.

Comment: While it is possible to make a (3,3) array of tuples, is that really what you need?  What's wrong with the (3,3,2) array of numbers?  Do you understand the difference?

Answer (score 1):

This will do the job:

```
new_grid = np.empty(len(grid), dtype='object')
new_grid[:] = grid
new_grid = new_grid.reshape(3, 3)
```

This outputs:

```
array([[(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3)],
       [(2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3)],
       [(3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3)]], dtype=object)
```

The object type will remain tuple:

```
type(new_grid[0, 0])
tuple
```

Answer (score 1):

`18` comes from the fact that you have a list of `9` tuples, each containing `2` items; thus, `9 * 2 = 18`. numpy automatically converts the tuples to part of the array.

You can either use [LeonardoVaz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71610738/17242583) or do it speedily with nested list comprehension:

```
reshaped_grid = [[grid[i+j] for j in range(3)] for i in range(0, len(grid), 3)]
```

Output:

```
>>> reshaped_grid
[
    [(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3)],
    [(2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3)],
    [(3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3)]
]
```

Comment: The output grid here is not what the question asks for.

Comment: @K-- Oops! Corrected :)